# Change an int value at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coding-style

I have a class with some constructors,a form with a command button and 1 public variable set to 20 at my "form.cs". How can i decrement the variable every time i click on the button until it becomes zero? I tried a few methods such as a loop inside the click event, a simple deduction in the constructor(variable = variable -1) but they dont work!
Tried this:

```
public void AssignSeat()
{
   seats = seats - 1;    
}
```

and then

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 Class1 = new Class1();
    Class1.AssignSeat();
    Class1.MSGbox();                     
}
```

It compiles and runs w/o errors but it never stops!

Comment: What do you mean with 'it never stops'? If you click the button, it will create a new class and call AssignSeat. If you click it again, it will create a new insstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are both the methods in the same class if yes, then you don't need to create an object for Class1 to access it.
2. Is the variable set as 20 every time you click on the button.
3. According to what you have written you are creating a new instance every time, So your issue arises.

Declare iCount & iTemp outside button click

int iCount = 0;
int iTemp = 20;

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (iCount == 0)
        {
            iTemp = 20;
            iCount++;
        }
        iTemp = iTemp - 1;
        MessageBox.Show(iTemp.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem but a new one has come up. This works absolutely fine BUT when i change form and i come back to this one iTemp is assigned to a value of 20 again,which i do not want to happen!I think i should declare iTemp at Form1 which is the first form which comes up when i run the program? I have 3 forms in total,form1 is the first form that comes up which has two command buttons and i choose form1 or form2.

Comment: You should declare iTemp in Form1 and pass the integer to your desired form. You could use property to set the value of the variable or pass it as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
Class1 Class1 = new Class1();
Class1.AssignSeat();
Class1.MSGbox();
```

... you're creating a *new* instance of `Class1` each time the button is clicked. Is the `button2_click` method already within `Class1`? If so, you just need to call `AssignSeat` - you don't need to create a new instance of the form.

(I'd also strongly advise *against* public variables, but that's another matter.)

Comment: no its not within Class1. Seems like im completely wrong, I just started C#.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a new instance of Class1 every time you click the button, then you decrement the seats of this newly created instance which gets destroyed as soon as the method ends.
Simply have a private variable of type Class1 inside your form (calling its costructor in the form's one) and use that:

```
public partial class Form1: Form {
    private Class1 _class1 = new Class1();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _class1.AssignSeat();
        _class1.MSGbox();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you're creating a new object each time you click the button, to solve your problem, make `seats` static.

This is a bad design, as @JonSkeet says